# What is the $() construct?

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar, template-haskell

I have been trying to find in the Haskell reference the use of this:

```
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "My Awesome Site"
    $(widgetFile "home")
```

Specifically:

```
$(widgetFile "home")
```

I know that the $ operator gives precedence to whatever is to the right of it, but I have not been able to comprehend the usage of $(). Anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not using the `$` application operator, but is involving a [Template Haskell slice](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html).

Very roughly, `widgetFile "home"` is code which is run at *compile time*: it generates Haskell code, which is then compiled as usual. It's a form of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) in Haskell.

Comment: I see so it has nothing to do with the $ operator. `widgetFile "home"` will then be responsible for generating this code on the fly at compile time?

Comment: @LuisDosReis Yes. It might for instance access an external file, process it, and generate some Haskell code depending on it. This can be used to obtain a vastly generalized `#include`, for instance, where the included file can use a different syntax.

Comment: Oh interesting so I can apply metaprogramming at manipulating different languages too.